# Mysql2::Error: Expression #2 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error:

`Mysql2::Error: Expression #2 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database_name_development.posts.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by: SELECT YEAR(created_at) AS year, MONTHNAME(created_at) AS month, COUNT(id) AS total FROM`posts`GROUP BY year, month ORDER BY year DESC, MONTH(created_at) DESC`

This is my model method

```
def self.archives
    Post.unscoped.select("YEAR(created_at) AS year, MONTHNAME(created_at) AS month, COUNT(id) AS total")
        .group("year, month")
        .order("year DESC, MONTH(created_at) DESC")
end
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably add `MONTH(created_at) AS monthnum` to the `SELECT` and add `monthnum` to the `GROUBY BY`. You have the month name aggregated but not the numeric value.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This seems to work and the page doesn't break, however how can I fix this in order to show the month's name instead?

Comment: Don't replace the `MONTHNAME()` call in select & group, _add_ an additional `MONTH()` call to what you already have.  If that seems to do the job I'll formulate it as a proper answer below.

Comment: You mean leave it as it currently is???

Comment: Please do cause I'm not sure I understood correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with MySQL 5.6, the old default behavior of allowing columns in `SELECT` expressions (or related `ORDER BY`) which did not also appear in `GROUP BY` when using aggregates changed to be more strict (and more like other RDBMS).

Since you have `MONTH(created_at)` in the `ORDER BY` to sort months numerically but do not have an equivalent expression in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`, you violate MySQL's requirements for `GROUP BY`. The solution is to add the numeric `MONTH()` expression to the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` so the grouping can properly aggregate. This should not affect performance.

```
def self.archives
    # Include a MONTH() expression in SELECT
    Post.unscoped.select("YEAR(created_at) AS year, MONTHNAME(created_at) AS month, MONTH(created_at) AS monthnum, COUNT(id) AS total")
        # Group with it as well
        .group("year, month, monthnum")
        # sort with the column alias
        .order("year DESC, monthnum DESC")
end
```

It may be possible to leave `MONTH(created_at) AS monthnum` out of the `.select()` if it is added to `.group()` (since you do not actually need to return the numeric values).  If that does work, you can't use the alias in `.group()` and `.order()` and instead must use the full expression.  I am uncertain this will work without error, but believe it might.

```
def self.archives
    Post.unscoped.select("YEAR(created_at) AS year, MONTHNAME(created_at) AS month, COUNT(id) AS total")
        # Add the expression to GROUP BY but not SELECT
        .group("year, month, MONTH(created_at)")
        .order("year DESC, MONTH(created_at) DESC")
end
```

Comment: Both options you wrote work, thank you very much! :-)